# ServiceStack - Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime even using JsConfig

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack, servicestack-text

I have looked at multiple resources online, but whatever I try just doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

using directives

```
using ServiceStack;
using ServiceStack.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
```

Code

```
JsConfig<DateTime>.DeSerializeFn = str => DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

using (var fs = File.Open(@"C:\temp\data.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    var data = CsvSerializer.DeserializeFromStream<List<Class>>(fs);
}
```

Also tried

```
JsConfig<DateTime>.DeSerializeFn = str => DateTime.ParseExact(str, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var list = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\temp\data.csv").FromCsv<List<Class>>();
```

And what is in the csv file?

StartDate,  FirstRedemptionDate,    FirstSubscriptionDate

01/08/2014 00:00,   31/08/2014 00:00,   01/08/2014 00:00

30/09/2014  00:00,  01/08/2015 00:00,   30/09/2013  00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because your CSV has both `,` delimiters and  space delimiters, when using `,` delimiters CSV is whitespace sensitive, e.g. your Headers should instead be:

```
StartDate,FirstRedemptionDate,FirstSubscriptionDate
```

As currently the header value of `'FirstRedemptionDate'` is `' FirstRedemptionDate'`.

I've made a change so headers are auto-trimmed in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/8e83147fe879f3075c20527db09805d33a81fa08) which allows your custom DateTime deserializer to be matched against headers with leading/trailing spaces which is available from the [latest v5.7.1 that's now on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Because you've also got leading whitespace in your date values you will also need to trim your value before parsing, e.g:

```
JsConfig<DateTime>.DeSerializeFn = str => 
    DateTime.ParseExact(str.Trim(), "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Which should now parse correctly using the latest [v5.7.1 of ServiceStack.Text on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thank you so much. Also for my actual code was using a nullable DateTime so I needed to include if (str == null) return null;